# X-editable Yii2 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I'm using Yii2 `dosamigos X-editable widget` based on `vitalet X-editable`. I'm using bootstrap 4. In my view file, I'm using nested layout by implementing the `beginContent()` method. While I'm not using the nested layout, the inline-editing feature works just fine. But while I'm using the nested layout; when I click the editable widget label, the editable field split into two input field on the left and right instead of a single input field. And when I click outside of the field, the input field won't disappear but appear beside the label (the one with "this is 'isiTema'" in the image).[image: screenshot]

I got this error in the console:

```
home:959 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.open (home:959)
    at ajax (home:1482)
    at home:1471
    at home:1820
```

Home:1820 
`})();</script><script src="/assets/ed7e27b/jquery.js"></script>`

Home:1511 `})();</script><script src="/assets/ed7e27b/jquery.js"></script>`

Home:1471 `xhr.open(settings.method || 'GET', url, true);`

Home:959 (and 958)

```
 //prevent logging AJAX calls to static and inline files, like templates 
    if (url.substr(0, 1) === '/' && !url.match(new RegExp("{{ excluded_ajax_paths }}"))) {
```

This is my `home` view file :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\url;
*/
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\HomeSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Homes';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

 <?php 
 $this->beginContent('@app/views/layouts/main-partial.php'); 
use dosamigos\editable\Editable;

$url=Url::to(['home/fetch']);
 Editable::widget( [
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'tema',
    'name'=>'tema',
    'id'=>'tema',
    'url' => $url,
    'type' => 'text',
    'mode' => 'pop',
]);
 Editable::widget( [
    'model' => $model,
    'name'=>'isiTema',
    'id'=>'isiTema',
    'url' => $url,
    'type' => 'text',
    'mode' => 'pop',
]);
    ?>

 <section id="intro">
    <div class="intro-container wow fadeIn">
    <h1 class="mb-4 pb-0"> 

    <a href="#" id="tema" name="tema" data-type="text" data-pk=<?=$model->id?> data-url=<?=Url::to(['home/fetch']);?> data-title="Enter username"><?=$model->tema?></a>
</h1>
<br/>
  <h1>  <a href="#" id="isiTema" name="isiTema" data-type="text" data-pk=<?=$model->id?> data-url=<?=Url::to(['home/fetch']);?> data-title="Enter username"><?=$model->isiTema?></a>
</h1>
<br/>

    </div>
</section>
<?php
$url = Url::to(['home/fetch']);

$script = <<< JS
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#tema').editable();
 $('#isiTema').editable();


});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
     $this->endContent();
?>
```

This is my nested layout `main-partial` view (I removed `$this->endPage()` because it didn't work without removing it) :

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View 
*/
/* @var $content string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\theEventAsset;
use yii\helpers\Url;

theEventAsset::register($this);

?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
        <?= $content ?>
</body>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder what's wrong. I try updating the asset's `editable's js and css` file with `Bootstrap 4 editable` version from https://github.com/Talv/x-editable/tree/develop/dist/bootstrap4-editable but to no avail. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The `$this->endPage()` should be there. Not supposed to be removed, my bad.

The problem actually lies on the include order of the `editable asset`. The asset should be included after the nested layout's assets are registered.

In my case, in my nested layout view it should be :

```
theEvent2Asset::register($this);
use dosamigos\editable\Editable;
```